# C++, return array from function

Tags: c++, arrays, function

Im building this subnet calculator but now im stuck, with array. I want to create new int function that will return array, but I don't know how I tried many things but still don't have idea, think it will have to do something with pointers. I want to create new function starting at "while(octet4>0)". so octet4 gets passed into function and function should return fully functional array which I can use then in main. Hope somebody will know answer for what im looking for, hope solution would not be too complicated because Im just learning programming and thought this would be fun project to take on.

```
int main() {
int i=0,j,q,s,size=8,temp;
int binary_ip[8];
int netmask;
int mask;
int octet1, octet2, octet3, octet4; 
string ip;
cout<<"Vnesite IP naslov, npr. 192.168.32.55:"<<endl;
cin>>ip;
cout<<"Vnesite netmasko, npr. /27:"<<endl;
cin>>netmask;   

stringstream stream(ip);
char ch; 
stream >> octet1 >> ch >> octet2 >> ch >> octet3 >> ch >> octet4;


while(octet4>0){
    binary_ip[i]=octet4%2;
    i++;
    octet4=octet4/2;
}

switch(i){
    case 7:binary_ip[7]=0;
    break;
    case 6:for(s=6;s<=7;s++)binary_ip[s]=0; 
    break;
    case 5:for(s=5;s<=7;s++)binary_ip[s]=0;
    break;
    case 4:for(s=4;s<=7;s++)binary_ip[s]=0;
    break;
    case 3:for(s=3;s<=7;s++)binary_ip[s]=0;
    break;
    case 2:for(s=2;s<=7;s++)binary_ip[s]=0;
    break;
    case 1:for(s=1;s<=7;s++)binary_ip[s]=0;
    break;
}

for(q=0;q<size/2;q++){
    temp=binary_ip[size-1-q];
    binary_ip[size-1-q]=binary_ip[q];
    binary_ip[q]=temp;}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: @renekton What's that switch-case for??

Comment: so you want to put your while loop in a function and return an array?

Comment: an "int function" returns an int by definition, not an array.

Comment: why don't you consider having your function fill-in the array, rather than return it. Then you don't hassle with memory allocation and deallocation.

Comment: If you want to return multiple `int`s, the simplest way would be to let the function return a `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Since the number of elements is known at compile-time, an `std::array` would probably be better.

Comment: Never mind, the number of elements is not known in advance, and the code (with or without Tyger’s answer) has a big potential vulnerability in a buffer overflow. You really should consider switching to `vector`, or better yet bounds-checking your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>


int array(int octet4, int binary_ip[]);

int main()
{
  int binary_ip[6];
  int octet4 = 55;
  int i = 0;
  i = array(octet4, binary_ip);//binary_ip passes in the address of the first element in the array
}
int array(int octet4, int binary_ip[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while(octet4>0)
    {
        binary_ip[i]=octet4%2;
        i++;
        octet4=octet4/2;
    }
    return i;
}
```

or you can use a vector like Daniel H suggested

```
void array(int octet4, std::vector<int> &binary_ip)
{

    while(octet4>0)
    {
    binary_ip.push_back(octet4%2);
    octet4=octet4/2;
    }

}
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> binary_ip;
  int octet4 = 55;
  array(octet4, binary_ip); 
}
```

Comment: Why pass in `i` instead of declaring it in the function?

Comment: because OP uses `i` in the switch statement

Comment: @DanielH I could've made an int function and return `i`and make `i` in main equal to the int function like this `i = array(octet4, binary_ip)`

Comment: Yeah, that seems neater. Then it’s returning a count of how many elements it made, not just incrementing a number.

Comment: @DanielH there I used a vector is this what you meant

Comment: Since a vector keeps track of the number of elements itself, then in that way you don’t need `i`; you can just use `binary_ip.size()` in the switch statement and not worry about `i`, but yes that should be better because it won’t give a memory error if I enter the number `1024`.

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- Use std::array instead of a regular C array. Those are easier to work with and you are already using standard library. http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/6-15-an-introduction-to-stdarray/
- Have your function fill-in the array, rather than create and return it:

  void MakeArray(int octet4, int binary_ip[8]) ;
- Use pointers, allocate array with "new" and free it with "delete". You'll need a way to know the size of the array, however.

Comment: I don’t think your second option would compile unless you made it a reference (or `int` pointer), unless array-to-pointer decay works differently than I think it does.

Comment: it compiles. Although the size in the array is basically ignored.

Comment: C arrays are never passed by value

Comment: Yeah, I knew that if it compiled it ignored the size, but I assumed it just wouldn’t let you specify a size because I’d never tried. I hope most compilers would at least give a warning for that.

Comment: it is certainly less common today. Useful just to specify the expectation of the function for somebody calling it, not for the compiler. Makes porting C->Java harder, though.